# Auto insert a standard comment header for every "newly generated java file" in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

I want to add some default text to every newly generated java file, so that I don't have to add it manually every time.

I've set the below configuration in eclipse:

[image]

But when I create a new java file, the default comment I found is blank,
like this:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.test.domain;

/**
 * @author rahul.tyagi1
 *
 */
public class Tinku {

}
```

Please help me to add an autocreated default comment without using the "Copyright Wizard" plugin.

Comment: It´s working for me on 4.4.2.

Comment: Is there any other setting which need to change for it? (I am using Eclipse Kepler)

Comment: I can confirm this is working in Luna with the settings shown in your screenshots. Are you sure you're letting eclipse create your new Java files?

Comment: Yes i am creating java classes by standard way....right-click on project then new......

Comment: Have you overridden these settings for your project? Click the "Configure Project Specific Settings..." link (top-right of your screenshot) to check.

Comment: ohh....yes right.....it was checked for this project......thanku Amos thanku very much.....the project specific settings were selected......now it is working thanks

Comment: @RahulTyagi: I've added an answer with the advice from my earlier comment... feel free to accept it if it helped you. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshots, your configuration actually looks correct, i.e. you have `${filecomment}` at the top of your pattern for "Code > New Java files" under "Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates", and editing the pattern under "Comments > Files" to suit your liking.

If your settings are correct for your general preferences, you should check whether the project-specific settings for your particular project are set to override the general settings. You can check this under the project's properties, or directly from the general settings by clicking the "Configure Project Specific Settings..." link (visible on the top right of your screenshot). If you have quite a few projects, tick "Show only projects with project specific settings".

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
* This is my file
*/

${package_declaration}

${typecomment}
${type_declaration}
```

Comment: Updated the answer... pls check

Comment: This is also giving me same result

Comment: I Think i may have changed some setting which is overriding this template, but don't know what :-(